# What is the best way to build TS assets in a NPM package

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have a NPM package with TypeScript based React components. When the package is installed, I would like to run a script that essentially runs `tsc` to compile the TS files, then delete the `src` folder when done.

```
// Excerpt from package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf ./dist && tsc",
  "install": "tsc",
  "postinstall": "rm -rf ./src tsconfig.json"
},
```

However, I noticed that the install hook always runs, whether you're running `npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:sparkbuzz/react-components.git`  but also when you run `npm install` from within the package (during development for example)

Is there a way to ensure the install script is only executed when the NPM package is remotely installed?

Comment: can you try with  "prepare":"npm run build" . BTW as i understand when you publish a typescript package npm automatically builds the package for you . https://itnext.io/step-by-step-building-and-publishing-an-npm-typescript-package-44fe7164964c